# Creating Relationship of inheritance class in Django Model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm building a tutor and coach website. I'm stuck on designing how the database should be like using the Django model. Please help correct me.

1. Entity:

   - User(username, password, name)
   - subclass of User

     - Coach(hour_rate, subject)
     - Student()
2. Relationship:

   - Tutoring(coach_username, tutor_username, date)

     class User(models.Model):
     username
3. Here is the Django model I implemented:

   ```
   class User(models.Model):
       username = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
       password = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = False, null = False)
       name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank = False, null = False)
       def __str__(self):
           return self.username + " " + self.name

   class Coach(User):
       subject = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False, null = False)
       hour_rate = models.FloatField(default = 0.00)
       def __str__(self):
           return self.username + " " + str(self.hour_rate)

   class Student(User):
       def __str__(self):
           return self.username + " " + self.name
   ```
4. Now that I have the inheritance setup, but I don't know how to setup a relationship where both attribute for is the same user entity. Please help, it's a mess.

   ```
   class tutoring(models.Model):
      coausr = models.ForeignKey(User)
      tutusr = models.ForeignKey(User)
      date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now = "True")
      def __str__(self):
           return self.coausr + " " + self.tutusr
   ```

If the whole structure of my Django model is wrong, or I'm not suppose to do this, please teach me the correct way. After setting up the relationship, please demonstrate how to interact with it in python shell. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should use `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`. It implements almost the entire authentication. Check it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/). The `Tutee` class seems unnecessary; it doesn't hold any other information beyond the `User`? Lastly, it's ok you have two fields of the same entity.

Comment: @tuliocasagrande The problem with the relationship I implemented, it does compile, it does work. What is the correct way to write it.

Comment: You need to inform a different `related_name`:
    `coausr = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='coausr')`;
    `tutusr = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tutusr')`.
Or you can use the subclasses:
    `coausr = models.ForeignKey(Coach)`;
    `tutusr = models.ForeignKey(Tutee)`.

Comment: [Use custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) to define your user. This way you can use all the goodness of authentication with your own attributes in the user.